# pandas read dataframe multi-header values

Tags: pandas, header, multi-index

I have this dataframe with multiple headers

```
name,   00590BL,    01090BL,    01100MS,    02200MS
lat,    613297, 626278, 626323, 616720
long,   5185127,    5188418,    5188431,    5181393
elv,    1833,   1915,   1915,   1499
1956-01-01, 1,  2,  2,  -2
1956-01-02, 2,  3,  3,  -1
1956-01-03, 3,  4,  4,  0
1956-01-04, 4,  5,  5,  1
1956-01-05, 5,  6,  6,  2
```

I read this as

```
dfr      =  pd.read_csv(f_name,
                            skiprows     = 0,
                            header       = [0,1,2,3], 
                            index_col    = 0,
                            parse_dates  = True
                            )
```

I would like to extract the value related the rows named 'lat' and 'long'.
A easy way, could be to read the dataframe in two step. In other words, the idea could be have two dataframes. I do not like this because it is not very elegant and it not seems to take advantage of pandas potentiality. I believe that I could use some feature related to multi-index.

what do you think?

Comment: `dfr.columns.get_level_values('lat')` and then the same for `long`?

Comment: Don't forget to use `skipinitialspace=True` to get a clean MultiIndex whithout any leading whitespaces. And don't forget to convert `lat` and `long` (and `elv`) to numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_level_values`:

```
dfr = pd.read_csv(f_name, skiprows=0, header=[0, 1, 2, 3], index_col=0, 
                  parse_dates=[0], skipinitialspace=True)

lat = df.columns.get_level_values('lat').astype(int)
long = df.columns.get_level_values('long').astype(int)
elv = df.columns.get_level_values('elv').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> lat.to_list()
[613297, 626278, 626323, 616720]

>>> long.to_list()
[5185127, 5188418, 5188431, 5181393]

>>> elv.to_list()
[1833, 1915, 1915, 1499]
```

If you only need the first row of column header, use `droplevel`

```
df = dfr.droplevel(['lat', 'long', 'elv'], axis=1).rename_axis(columns=None))
print(df)

# Output
            00590BL  01090BL  01100MS  02200MS
1956-01-01        1        2        2       -2
1956-01-02        2        3        3       -1
1956-01-03        3        4        4        0
1956-01-04        4        5        5        1
1956-01-05        5        6        6        2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the `.loc` method to select the rows by their label. For example, you could use the following code to extract the 'lat' values:

`lat_values = dfr.loc['lat']`

And similarly, you could use the following code to extract the 'long' values:

`long_values = dfr.loc['long']`

Alternatively, you can use the `.xs` method to extract the values of the desired level.

`lat_values = dfr.xs('lat', level=1, axis=0) long_values = dfr.xs('long', level=1, axis=0)`

Both these approach will extract the values for 'lat' and 'long' rows from the dataframe and will allow you to access it as one dataframe with one index.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but It seems not working. This is the error "*** KeyError: 'lat'".

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. If you are getting a "KeyError: 'lat'" it means that the row with the label 'lat' does not exist in the DataFrame. The `.loc` method is used to select rows by label, so if the label is not present in the DataFrame, an error will be raised. 

It's possible that the rows you want to extract are not labeled 'lat' and 'long' but rather they are in the subcolumn level. In that case, you can access them using the `.loc` method on the subcolumn level of the DataFrame.